# Where do I start when creating a microcontroller interfacing program with a GUI?

Tags: user-interface, microcontroller

I'm in a senior design class for my college's computer engineering program.  I'm not very good with Embedded Systems.  I need to create a program that can send instruction to a microcontroller and it should have a GUI. Someone else is programming the microcontroller so I'm mostly just responding to what they will output to me.  I really have no idea where to start with this, I'm a little swamped/overwhelmed on my final semester. Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Additional info: We are using a TI-msp430f2274 for the device and it's really just outputting the readings of 3 gyroscopes. I'm thinking about using GTK to create the GUI but I am looking to see if there's something better.

Edit: My project is a roller alignment tool that uses gyroscopes to compare two rollers.  The program would send an instruction to "zero" the tool to one roller and receive a stream of data that says the offset difference of the next roller.

We are using a TTL-232R cable with a UART interface and the program should work on Windows. I have no idea how you talk to it.  College has crushed me.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: And what languages are you comfortable with? I'd personally write this in tcl or node.js since it could be done with around two dozen lines of code in tcl or around three dozen lines in node.js.

Comment: I am familiar with Java and C (but not C++) and I had to use TCL at my intership for one seperate project and hated it. I'll take a look at node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a windows machine then Visual Studio and a Windows Forms Application could do the trick. I've used it previously to interface with temperature sensors and other control equipment via USB and other projects involving reading from USB Human Interface Devices. So without understanding the specifics of your project, as an IDE Visual Studio, I think, is the best and most intuitive and using the Windows API you can achieve a lot with your code.

[Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads)

HTH.

p.s. I write most of my code in VB using VS but it will support other languages too...

Edit: some example code of reading from a com port:

```
Sub ReceiveSerialData()
    ' Receive strings from a com port 
    Dim comport as string = "COM 6" 'or whatever com you want...
    Dim baud as integer = 9600 'or whatever baud you want...

    Try
        com = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort(comport)
        com.ReadTimeout = 10000
        com.BaudRate = baud

        While (com.IsOpen)
            Dim Incoming As String = com.ReadLine()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit While
            Else
                'do something here with your com data
                'i.e. display it in a rich text box, or whatever...
            End If
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' display your errors here if you wish....
    End Try
End Sub
```

I think the other answers though, esp about using tcl probably make more sense from an embedded systems point of view. I simply have no experience with them whatsoever hence my VB'ness. :-)

Comment: I will take a look at it. It sounds like it would work. Compiling and running it on Windows made QT or GTK seem like it wouldn't work. Would you recommend writing it VB? I'm super new to all this.

Comment: VB is easy enough to get going in my opinion, the only reason I chose it for the apps I've written is simply I was in that mood at the time. C++ for example would work just as well, but I prefer the syntax of VB. Each to their own. I'll edit my answer with an example in VB to read from a comport so you can get a feel for what I did...

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you've used tcl before, I'm giving my answer in tcl since IMHO it's the easiest way to do this and therefor the right tool for the right job.

The core advantage of tcl (and indeed one of the reasons it's loved by its fans) is that it's very, very cross-platform. While in other languages cross platform simply means "can run on multiple platforms" but still requires you to use different API depending on the platform, tcl smooths out platform differences providing a unified API across platforms.

Tcl treats serial ports like files so you just `open` it to talk to it. Granted, different platforms provides different ways of naming the ports. So on Windows, to talk to the serial port you simply do:

```
set rs232 [open COM1 w+]
```

On unixen (Linux, MacOSX etc.) you'd do:

```
set rs232 [open /dev/ttyS0 w+]
```

To set the baud rate and parity bits you can now do

```
fconfigure $rs232 -mode "9600,n,8,1"
```

Be sure to also configure the serial port to binary mode otherwise tcl will re-interpret "\n" for you depending on your OS:

```
fconfigure $rs232 -mode "9600,n,8,1" -translation binary -blocking 0
```

The "blocking" bit is to set it to non-blocking mode so that we can write event oriented code which is critical for UI apps since we don't want the IO to block our UI.

So now for a simple program that reads data from the serial port:

```
package require Tk ;# in case we're running in tclsh

if {[catch {set rs232 [open COM1 w+] err}]} {
    tk_dialog .error Error "Could not open COM1: $err" error 0 OK
}
fconfigure $rs232 -mode "9600,n,8,1" -translation binary -blocking 0

# Draw a simple UI do dump data to:
pack [label .l -text "Gyroscope outputs:"]
pack [label .g1 -textvariable gyro1]
pack [label .g2 -textvariable gyro2]
pack [label .g3 -textvariable gyro3]

# Now the fun part, read from the serial continuously with fileevent:
set buffer ""
fileevent $rs232 readable {
    append buffer [read $rs232]

    # Here, you need to parse the data returned.
    # Due to the byte-wise nature of serial ports the data read may not be
    # complete so we need to check if it's complete. "Completeness" depends
    # on you. For example the data packet may end with a newline. Or it may
    # simply be a timeout between data packets.

    if {[message_is_complete $buffer]} {
        set gyros [parse_message $buffer]
        set buffer ""

        # Update the UI:
        foreach x $gyros y {gyro1 gyro2 gyro2} {
            set $y $x
        }
    }
}
```

Minus the comments and empty lines that's just 16 lines of code. You can of course go further and implement a more fancy UI rather than just text labels.

If you need to send data to the microcontroller simply `puts` to it. Just remember to override tcl's automatic newline termination:

```
puts -nonewline $rs232 $somedata
```

Use tcl's `binary` command if you need to format to and from binary.

Answer (score 0):

I personally still prefer tcl for this because you can get a prototype up and running to read the output from your hardware in under 5 minutes. But you also mentioned interest in a node.js solution. So here's an alternative starting point for node.js

First you need to install node.js. This may or may not be trivial depending on your OS. You will need Python 2.x (not 3.0) installed on your system in order to compile node.js modules writen in C (and even node.js itself). Even if you're installing a binary distribution of node you will still have to compile the serial port library since it's not included in the core.

Next you will need to install the `serialport` module. The instructions vary depending on your OS. See the npm page for the module: https://npmjs.org/package/serialport

Once you've got things up and running you can simply communicate with your serial port using the serialport module:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var rs232 = new SerialPort("COM1", {
    baudrate: 57600
}, false);
```

Again, like the tcl case, the name of the serial port depends on your OS. The above is an example for Windows. For unixen you'd do:

```
var rs232 = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS0", {
    baudrate: 57600
}, false);
```

For UI, node doesn't have a core toolkit like tcl. There are many libraries on npm available allowing you to use QT or GTK or some other widget set. But the most common way of doing UI on node is to simply run it as a web server and connect to it with your web browser. The downside of this is a little additional complexity and the need to mess with HTML. The upside is HTML & CSS! Which means you can leverage tools like CSS3 effects and jQuery to create a really slick UI with very little effort.

Unfortunately, writing an interactive webapp (even a simple one) is fairly involved so I won't be providing a "simple" example implementation. I'd only suggest you read up on the more popular frameworks like [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) and templating libraries like [dust](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/) or [handlebars](https://npmjs.org/package/handlebars). You may also want to take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to simplify the implementation of real-time communications between your server and the web browser.